# Shorter way to write linq query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Need to write a shorter linq query for the code below

```
enrolledPortfoliosVM = enrolledPortfoliosVM
    .Where(ep => ep.ProductCategories != null && ep.ProductCategories
        .Where(pc => pc.ProductTypes != null && pc.ProductTypes
            .Where(pt => pt.Benefits != null && pt.Benefits
                .Where(b => b.EndDate != null && b.EndDate > currentDate)
                .ToList().Count > 0)
            .ToList().Count > 0)
        .ToList().Count > 0)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Why do you need to write a shorter Linq query? If it works, then it works. If you just desire to polish/improve the readability of your code, then http://codereview.stackexchange.com is perhaps a  better place for seeking comments and responses.

Comment: Rather than making it shorter, try making it better in other ways. For example, `ToList().Count > 0` is almost always worse than `.Any()`.  Not because `Any()` is shorter, but because it better expresses the idea of "not empty".  Also, if you have a jar with some number of pennies in it, **how many pennies do you have to count before you know it is not zero?**

Comment: You don't need those null checks, but anyway it is a weird query.

Comment: Change `ep => ep.ProductCategories != null && ep.ProductCategories` to `ep => ep.ProductCategories?.Where(...`

Comment: @CetinBasoz why do you say the `null` checks are not required? Calling `.Where` (or `.Any`) on a `null` object would throw an `ArgumentNullException`. For example if: `enrolledPortfoliosVM = new List<SomeType> {new SomeType {ProductCategories = null} }`

Comment: @RufusL, with Any those would be skipped. The edge case is it is created anew and there no ProductCategories yet. You can add a null check to top where.

Comment: The null checks should not be required in the first place because **it is almost always wrong to represent an empty collection as null.** Make the implementations of the properties return an empty collection, and never return null.

Answer (score 2):

```
var  portfolios = enrolledPortfoliosVM
                    .Where(ep => ep.ProductCategories
                        .Any(pc => pc.ProductTypes
                            .Any(pt => pt.Benefits
                                .Any(b => b.EndDate > currentDate)
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    .ToList();
```

For clarification, this returns a collection of whatever the enrolledPortfoliosTypeVM is. Here is a sample with MS SQL server's northwind database:

```
Customers
    .Where(c => c.Orders
        .Any(o => o.ShippedDate > new DateTime(1997,1,1)))
```

produces this SQL:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 DateTime = '1997-01-01 00:00:00.000'
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[CustomerID], [t0].[CompanyName], [t0].[ContactName], [t0].[ContactTitle], [t0].[Address], [t0].[City], [t0].[Region], [t0].[PostalCode], [t0].[Country], [t0].[Phone], [t0].[Fax]
FROM [Customers] AS [t0]
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
    FROM [Orders] AS [t1]
    WHERE ([t1].[ShippedDate] > @p0) AND ([t1].[CustomerID] = [t0].[CustomerID])
    )
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but probably because you ignored @RufusL's question about why you said it's okay to ignore null checks and then went ahead and wrote an answer without them anyway. The question still remains why you think it's okay to call `.Any()` on a potentially null object.

Comment: @itsme86, I didn't ignore it. With Any it doesn't matter if it is null. Essentially we are asking "are there any?". We wouldn't ask that if there wasn't a potential to be any nulls. That doesn't explain the downvote. My guess is that, the downvoted didn't even understand it and downvoted just because she\he can. This is the downside of SO, one can downvote just because she\he doesn't understand and can do it without any explanation.

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding about the null check. Having an empty collection (which `.Any()` checks) is different from the a non-existent collection (which the null check does). If you don't believe me, try `List<object> list = null; bool any = list.Any();` and see what happens.

Comment: @itsme86, It is not realistic to have a null list instead of an empty collection. Who would hand code a list to do this. The source is likely a database where you have empty collection, not a null list. If you want to work with null lists instead and be purist, you can add null checks. I based my view on real world usage, using a database.